# Reuse a react component with different method calls

Tags: reactjs, components

I want to create a component with a simple form, lets say with 4 input fields and a button to submit. When the user clicks submit, a POST request will be made. 
But then I want to reuse the same component to make a PUT request. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a function from a parent component to you child component (the form):

https://codesandbox.io/s/4x3zjwxwkw

```
const App = () => (
  <div>
    <CreateRecipe />
    <UpdateRecipe />
  </div>
);

class CreateRecipe extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Do POST recipe");
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MyForm title="POST Recipe" onSubmit={this.onSubmit} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class UpdateRecipe extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Do GET recipe");
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <MyForm title="GET Recipe" onSubmit={this.onSubmit} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const MyForm = ({ title, onSubmit }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>{title}</h2>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
        <input type="text" />
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**EDIT**: Per the comment, you can absolutely separate the `POST` and `GET` submit functions, but this duplicates logic a bit. What could be better is to have the `<App />` component own the two submit functions, and pass them respectively to `<UpdateRecipe />` and `<PostRecipe />`, maybe even the titles too! I'll let you compose this however you'd like, but hopefully this shows you the flexibility of React.

Comment: Would it be ok to create three seperate components, one with the post method, another with the update method, and the last one with the form itself?

Comment: @aye Yep, definitely. Just updated the answer, and the sandbox link. If you absolutely don't want to have the `POST` and `GET` functions in the same component, you can duplicate the logic in both `CreateRecipe` and `UpdateRecipe`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in a method as a prop to the component - that way you can define the functionality outside of the component and let it execute it within the components scope.

An example of this would be passing in a onPress event to a Button, or an onClick event to any other component.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the method into the component as a `prop` and then reference props in your submit function like this:

```
submit = () => {
     var data = {
        method: this.props.method,
        ...
     };

   fetch('/url/', data);
}
```